# Trying to animate a SKNode inside a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have programmatically created a SKView inside of my UIView. Now I want to animate a new SKNodes in all directions, starting in the middle (this works) depending on the view that is passed through. All works fine except for the fact that the ending position of the SKNode is weird. Instead of shooting in all directions, it is going inside of a corner, way out of the view's boundaries. It should never go out of the view's boundaries. I am converting the CGPoint to my scene from the View.

This is my code:

```
func animateExplosion(sender: UIButton){

    let star = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ExplodingStar")
    let starHeight = sender.frame.height / 3
    star.size = CGSize(width: starHeight, height: starHeight)
    var position = sender.frame.origin
   position = self.sceneScene.convertPoint(fromView: position)
    star.position = position
    let minimumDuration = 1
    let maximumDuration = 2
    let randomDuration = TimeInterval(RandomInt(min: minimumDuration * 100, max: maximumDuration * 100) / 100)
    let fireAtWill = SKAction.move(to: getRandomPosition(view: sender), duration: randomDuration)
    let rotation = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(randomAngle()), duration: Double(randomDuration))
    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: randomDuration)
    let scaleTo = SKAction.scale(to: starHeight * 2, duration: randomDuration)
    let group = SKAction.group([fireAtWill, rotation]) //for testing no fade out or remove parent
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([group])

    if randomAmountOfExplodingStars > 0{
        randomAmountOfExplodingStars -= 1
        sceneScene.addChild(star)
        star.run(sequence)
        animateExplosion(sender: sender)
    }
}
```

the getRandomPosition where the bug properly is:

```
func getRandomPosition(view: UIView) -> CGPoint{
    let direction = RandomInt(min: 1, max: 4)
    var randomX = Int()
    var randomY = Int()

    if direction == 1{
        randomX = Int(view.frame.width / 2)
        randomY = RandomInt(min: -Int(view.frame.height / 2), max: Int(view.frame.height / 2))
    }
    if direction == 2{
        randomX = RandomInt(min: -Int(view.frame.width / 2), max: Int(view.frame.width / 2))
        randomY = Int(view.frame.height / 2)
    }
    if direction == 3{
        randomX = -Int(view.frame.width / 2)
        randomY = RandomInt(min: -Int(view.frame.height / 2), max: Int(view.frame.height / 2))
    }
    if direction == 4{
        randomX = RandomInt(min: -Int(view.frame.width / 2), max: Int(view.frame.width / 2))
        randomY = -Int(view.frame.height / 2)
    }
    var randomPosition = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
    //randomPosition = self.sceneScene.convertPoint(fromView: randomPosition)
    return randomPosition
}
```

I know that code looks awful, but it should do the trick right? The passed through view is a UIButton inside of a UIView. The SKView shares exactly the same constrains as that UIView. The animation should start in the middle and end somewhere to the boundaries of the passed view.

Answer (score 0):

Yay got it to work finally. So dumb I did not notice before. The sender would be always a child inside of a UIView which is smaller. The return function was great, but the SKNode should not *move* to the returned function, but *moved by*.

Updated code:

```
let randomPositionOfSender = getRandomPosition(view: sender)
        let fireAtWill = SKAction.moveBy(x: randomPositionOfSender.x, y: randomPositionOfSender.y, duration: randomDuration)
```